# Why invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1...'?

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop a program that sums a thousand times '1' in a variable with Python.

```
str='1,1,1,1,1,1... to 1000
 list=str.split(",")
 Sum=0
 for i in list:
    Sum+=int(i)
```

it gives me an error, I'm wondering why?

Comment: Note: `list` is a builtin type just like `dict` or `str` in python, so please use other names for your vars since you will get into trouble later if you replace the builtins. You also use the var `Sum` that do not conflict with anything, but the lowercase `sum` is a builtin so there could be some confusion here as well. So think about your naming and keep up the fun :)

Comment: Do you want to do the addition with `'1'` or `1`? The first is a string and the second is a number. I suspect you want the numbers, but according to the description in your question you want the string.

Comment: You have to use `','.join(['1']*1000)` intead of `'1,1,1,1,1,1... to 1000'`

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to provide a [mre]? It is not really clear what output you expect, nor what exactly you are working with. The code taken at face value fails with a ``SyntaxError``, and applying obvious fixes leads to a slightly different failure than in the title. It would likely also be useful to clarify why you think *any* variation of "1,1,1... to 1000" would be sensible for Python, so that this misconception can be cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

Your construction is not correct. What do you think it's supposed to do?

```
str='1,1,1,1,1,1... to 1000'
```

Because your error is when `Sum+=int(i)` and `i` equals `'1...'` which is obviously an invalid literal for int().

Try instead:

```
s = ','.join(['1']*1000)
Sum = sum(int(i) for i in s.split(','))
print(Sum)

# Output:
1000
```

**Don't use builtin names as variable names. NEVER**

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1...'` because you have passed the str varibale exactly the way it is on the question ( i.e `str='1,1,1,1,1,1... to 1000` ). You cannot expect python to to understand english right ? :)

Try this instead:

```
ones = ','.join(['1']*1000)
one_list = ones.split(",")
Sum=0
for i in list:
    Sum+=int(i)
```

Note: I changed the variable names because using python built-in names as variable names is not recommended as the names will not work as they are supposed to.